# WordPress WP_Query Loop Seems Differs From Actual Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a `WP_Query` on a page to retrieve some records with a custom post type and a particular meta value.

The request and count look correct, but when I actually loop over the records I get all the records with the custom post type, as if the meta value isn't being applied (i.e. it looks like I'm getting what I'd see in the default loop - not what I'd get using my custom query).

Here is the query set up (with some debugging information)...

```
  <?php
    $args= array(
      'post_type' => 'videos',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'offset' => 0,
      'meta_key' => 'custom_field',
      'meta_value' => '1'
    );
    $videoQuery = new WP_Query($args);

    echo $videoQuery->request;

    echo '-->' . $videoQuery->found_posts;
  ?>
```

The query from `->request` is as expected:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_field' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1' ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'videos'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 4
```

Found posts is 1 as expected too:

> -->1

If I run the query, I get the ID I am expecting to see.

But when I loop the results, I get a ton of records output (they look like the records I would find in the default loop rather than the records for my WP_Query):

```
  <?php if ($videoQuery->have_posts()) : ?>
  <div>
    <?php while ($videoQuery->have_posts()) : $videoQuery->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
      <?php the_field('custom_thing_video'); ?>
      <?php the_field('custom_thing_name'); ?>
      <div class="tax">
          <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'video' ); ?>
      </div>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

What have I missed that will give me the correct information in the loop?

Comment: To clarify, you get lots of `<article><div class="tax"></div></article>`? Are there any `pre_get_posts` filters in the game?

Comment: Hi @janh - I get lots of those articles. I'm on a page that would show the custom post types and it looks like the "default results" rather than my custom query results.

Comment: That's very strange. Is all of this running inside the main loop (e.g. executed many times)? `get_posts` does use WP_Query internally, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi @janh - I put this before the main loop while developing. I also tried removing the main loop entirely. Same result. `get_posts` is in there now and works... I'm stumped as the only thing different to other working queries is that Advanced Custom Fields are being used quite a bit in this one.

Comment: But you're sure that this is actually what's happening, and there's not another loop running outside before/after this one that is actually the culprit? Is `$videoQuery->found_posts` consistent before/during/after the while loop?

Comment: The page is an archive page, it has `get_header();`, then it creates a drop-down based on `get_terms(...)` and then it is this query. The terms loop is definitely ended and the results that come out are not repeated like I imagine they would be within another loop.

Comment: Can you boil it down to a reproducible minimum test case? I'd be happy to help debug, but it will probably be specific to your environment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does calling wp_reset_postdata() before the $videoQuery have any effect?

Comment: @git-e-up I just gave that a go - I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this works - but seems to go against the recommendations... I'd be delighted to accept another answer that does things with `WP_Query`.

The arguments are identical... but I'm using `get_posts` and then `foreach` over the posts.

```
  <?php
    $args= array(
      'post_type' => 'videos',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'offset' => 0,
      'meta_key' => 'custom_field',
      'meta_value' => '1'
    );
    $videos = get_posts($args);
  ?>

  <?php if ($videos) : ?>
  <div>
    <?php foreach($videos as $video) {
      $videoId = $video->ID ?>
    <article>
      <?php echo get_field('custom_thing_video', $videoId); ?>
      <?php echo get_field('custom_thing_name', $videoId); ?>
      <div class="tax">
          <?php echo get_the_term_list($videoId, 'video'); ?>
      </div>
    </article>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```